# Why is the csrf token checked when i use api middelware

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5

i am using laravel 5.2 whit the predefined middelwares 'api' and 'web'. in the kernel file its stated that web would use quite some while api only checks throttle:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];
```

in my routes i grouped the api routes and applied only 'api'

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['api']), function(){
    Route::post('test', 'TestController@testfunction');
}); // End of api Group
```

but when i send a post to /api/test it throws the crsf token mismatch. if i put the 'api/test' to the exception in the VerifyCsrftoken.php it works again. i cant figure out why the crsf token gets checked if not defined as a middelware for the route. Does anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Is your `api` route group in the root of your routes file? Perhaps it is contained within another group with `web` middleware?

Comment: it is in the root

Answer (score 1):

CSRF is a "middleware" registered globally in App\Http\Kernel.php. Removing it will default to no CSRF protection (Laravel4 behavior).
To enable it in a route: 
Create a short-hand key in your

`app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

`protected $middleware = [
  // ....
  'csrf'  => 'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
];`

You can now enable it to any Route:

`$router->post('url', ['middleware' => 'csrf', function() {
         ... 
        }]);`

Not really elegant but may be a spot on on your question, try it.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i played a little bit around with what you mentioned and it works, but 95% of the routes have to use csrf and they are in many groups. while trying all of that i know for sure know that all routes getting the web middelware for some reason. did you ever had the same issue?